# How to validate empty Select box option with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I have a very simple `Project` form with a `name` field and a select box with various `Client` names in it:

```
<%= f.label :name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :client_id %><br/>
<% options = current_user.clients.all.map { |client| [client.name, client.id] } %>
<%= f.select(:client_id, options, {:prompt => 'Select...'}) %>
```

Now when a user hits submit without actually selecting a `Client` from the select box, an error is returned saying that a `Client` with ID " " cannot be found.

Is there any way to change my controller code so that it works?

```
def create
  client = current_user.clients.find(params[:project][:client_id])
  @project = client.projects.build(params[:project])
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created."
    redirect_to @project
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

It's the local `client` variable that causes the trouble but I don't know how to fix it so that errors will be handled by the validation methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above code is trying to fetch a `client object by passing id as nil`. Following code should work, provided there is a `validation for client record` before saving project record.

```
def create
  client = current_user.clients.find(params[:project][:client_id]) rescue nil
  unless client
    @project = Project.new(params[:project]) # Required for making the form fields pre-populated
    @project.valid? # this line will populate the error messages
    render :action => "new"
    return
  end

  @project = client.projects.build(params[:project])
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created."
    redirect_to @project
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For your controller, you can avoid the error by rescuing `nil` or by checking `params[:project][:client]` is not blank before calling `find`. Note that if the record is not found with a given project => id, it will still throw you an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` record not found error.

For the model,

```
class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :size, :inclusion => { :in => %w(small medium large),
    :message => "%{value} is not a valid size" }
end
```

This is from the Rails guide and you can use `:inclusion`  to validate the  `Select` box.

It will catch errant values (i.e if the user spoofs a POST) as well, acting like an enumeration field.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#inclusion